# I am using a raspberry Pi model 3b plus with 4 cores. I have 3 different sensors; can I run each on a different core within the python script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using a raspberry Pi model 3b plus with 4 cores. I have 3 different EMG sensors. Can I run each on a different core within the python script?  If so, how do I designate which sensors run on which cores?  Currently, I have a python program that allows each sensor to have its data recorded within a csv file for later analysis, but I have sensors that drop out or do not start.  I'm hoping that using a different core for each sensor might solve this. I tried using different threads, but this did not fix this problem of some sensors not starting, starting late, or stopping early when trying to acquire all of the sensor data in a synchronized fashion.

Comment: Try using `multiprocessing` module, or even `supervisor`. The OS should do this automatically for you. I'm not aware of using Python to "target" any core

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity

Comment: Thx. Giving it a try. Found some info on this on Raspberry Pi website.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you shared your current threaded code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.